# Brands of KFP peanut butter in the US

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, product-recommendation

Does anyone know which brands of peanut butter are Kosher for Passover in the US?  Alternatively, I have heard that there is a list for Sepharadim of KFP products that contain Kitniyoth. Can someone direct me to said list?

Comment: http://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-news/in-time-for-passover-2013-ou-kosher-announces-new-ou-kitniyot-certification-symbol/

Answer (score 3):

I checked the JSOR list, and found no information about KFP peanut butter (see here: http://www.jsor.org/PassoverList_2012_RevC.pdf)

I would suggest buying unshelled peanuts or any shelled peanuts acceptable per the list and grinding them yourself in a Pesahdik food processor or other grinder.

Answer (score 3):

For 2014 (I don't know about earlier), Manischewitz began a line of products called "Kitni" that were OU Kitniyot; one of them was a peanut butter. I contacted the OU and and they said the only ingredient in that product offensive to Ashkenazim is the peanuts. (So this is kind of "kosher for Passover for Sephardim as well as those Ashkenazim whose custom allows peanuts.")