# Kitniot derivatives during Pesach

Tags: halacha, passover, kitniyos-semigrain-legume

Every Pesach, I see candy by a company called [Joyva](http://www.joyva.com). This would not be exceptional, except for the note on the back which in paraphrase, reads:

Note: this product contains liquid derivatives from kitniot (henceforward, *shemen kitniot*), which are kosher for Pesach according to the opinion of R' Yitzchok Elchonon Spektor זצ”ל.

1. How does R' Spektor permit shemen kitniot?
2. Who agrees with him that it is permissible?
3. Do any Ashkenazi* communities hold by this leniency in this day and age?
4. Who is the mashgiach on Joyva's products, R' D.I. Scheinkopf?

*Here, unlike in many of my questions about German nusach and minhag, Ashkenazi refers to the general European populace, with the obvious exception of the Sephardi and Balkan kehillot.

Comment: See Beer Yitzchak OC 11

Comment: When we grew up shemen kitniot was allowed, by the Rov in our Yekkish Kehilo.

Comment: R. Michel Shurkin (Ashkenazi, but not German) told me that when he was growing up everyone used peanut oil on Pesach. I believe R. Kook permits it as well.

Comment: @DannySchoemann and Mevaqesh, here, unlike in some of my other posts, Ashkenazi refers to general non-Sephardi/Mizrachi kehillot, including the kehillot hachassidim.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, where was this kehillah?

Comment: @mevaqesh Peanuts may not even be kitniyot at all.

Comment: @DoubleAA, How do you figure? Of course, because of minhag avoteinu b'yadeinu, it probably is now.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt But it's not minhag avoteinu if our grandparents didn't do it... Plenty of people ate peanuts on pesach in europe. See Igrot Moshe OC 3 63 who permits it (unless you have a specific old family tradition otherwise)

Comment: @DoubleAA, I don't know about in Europe, but I do know that my grandfather ז”ל, did not eat peanuts during Pesach after coming to the US.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Your personal traditional familial halachic quirks are perhaps interesting and binding on you, but not on Judaism as a whole (is RMF's point). If you traditionally didn't drink orange juice in red cups, the same discussion would apply.

Comment: @DoubleAA, no disagreement. However, on the other hand, I have never seen pesachdik peanut butter, either.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Well, industrial kashrut market their products to as many as possible, after all. See too http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/45259/759

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt - you asked "where was this kehillah?" - It was the Adas Yeshurun of Johannesburg, South Africa. AFAIK we didn't get a different Psak in the Etz Chaim in Strasbourg, France, either.

Answer (score 1):

I heard from R. Nota Greenblatt that R. Moshe Feinstein permitted all kitniyos derivatives. This is his psak as well.

Comment: Kitniyus Alcohol as well?